# Interfacing SPI signal based sensor to ROS? any idea?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm thinking to interface SPI based sensor to ROS.
Anyone have a good idea to this end?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40861/interfacing-spi-signal-based-sensor-to-ros?-any-idea?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use an arduino for the SPI interface. Together with rosserial, you should be able to nicely integrate this into ROS.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Typically, if you wish to interface an SPI sensor with a PC, you need some kind of bridge. My preferred option is an Arduino microcontroller that acts as an SPI to USB bridge. The Arduino has no problem communicating with an SPI device, and then you can use [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial) to communicate with the Arduino to receive/send data to the device.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3